# How to get the Sum in Cross tab in Crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, crosstab

I am using Cross tab in `Crystal Reports` for getting dynamic generation of rows and column.
And i need the total summary  in the summary field.

I am not able to find the sum function there.  I am using `VS 2008` and `Crystal report  Version=10.5.3700.0.`

Comment: Can u post that code what ever u have tried..?

Comment: In crosstab properties there should be checkboxes for row and column summaries? If both are checked, total sum should be visible too.

Comment: yeah.. i got the solution. The problem was, data type of the parameter was string in xsd file. i have changed string to int32. The sum() has came for me. Now it works fine..